# How many physical processors does Windows 8.1 Support?

Tags: cpu, windows-8-preview

This question was already asked for windows 8 and i'm hoping (albeit fairly sure that no) that microsoft changed their policies.
Does anyone know if windows 8.1 now support > 2physical CPU in any form? I'd like to build a monster but have it dual boot windows server & windows 8.1 for development purposes (by monster i mean 80 to 160 cores), i know i will be limited to 512GB of ram but i can live with that, but 2 physical CPU is way way low.

Comment: @Karan that really is the only approach that begins to make sense with this to me. Although, if you can afford 80-160 cores for development I see no reason to dual boot, just build a Win 8 machine or run it in a VM for $100 - 1000.

Comment: I need a that large win 8 machine, not a smaller version running on the same machine, & so it wouldn't help at all i think (unless hyperv cores only count as logical cores? If so that could be a workaround, i could hyper V, run a windows 8.1 VM & assign all 160 logical cores to it). Would that work? Or would windows 8 detect that & complain?

Comment: Do you really need more than Windows 8 already supports?  We expect you to ask **actual** questions you face.

Comment: Yes i do (and already use that in servers) i now am looking for an alternative to use this on windows 8 too (as currently i'm split between a remote rented server and my local machine) because some apps are checking for a server version & some for a non server os, i'd like a single physical machine for all this as i'm definately not shelling out the cash for this kind of machine twice. I actually do need more than is physically possible, but i do with what exists, so as far as i know the max i can physically buy is 8 physical proc at 10 cores each * HT = 8X10X2 = 160 threads, with 2-4TB ram

Comment: And all that would be easier if it was for a problem that could scale to multiple machine, but it's not the case, i use massively parallel things that aren't chunkable in smaller parts (algorithm works on all the data at once, so you can't say "i take 100 machines, give each of them 1% of the data", you'd have to say "i take 100 machines, give each of them 100% of the data & ram usage, and have them join all the time". Besides just buying the rights to the program i use in source form + rewriting it would be more costly than such a machine

Answer (score 0):

Well 80 to 160 logical processors, not psyhical ... 
Latest Intel processor have 10 psyhical cores, and that is Intel® Xeon® Processor E7-8870 
(30M Cache, 2.40 GHz, 6.40 GT/s Intel® QPI), well is not last but is the strongest :)

Maximum of RAM is 4TB, amazing :)

Comment: Yes but if it's still 2 physical processors, then you're not going to hit anywhere near as many, atm the best is 10 core / 20 threads from intel, that's only 40 threads out of 2 physical CPU, way way bellow my need, is why i'm hoping they lifted that in win 8.1

Comment: What does the limits that Intel has placed on their platform have to do with Windows in the slightest?

Comment: It's not related to intel at all, it's about windows 8 limiting the max number of "physical" CPU, i need more cores than it's possible today with 2 "physical" CPUs, i need all 8 for a 8 way type machine.

Comment: Windows Server 2012 does not have those same limits…